# How can I set a different .bashrc PS1 depending on the directory I'm in?

Tags: git, bashrc, ps1

I have the [`git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) script setup in my `.bashrc` file which 
gives me the useful git information in my prompt. This is great for small repos, but when I `cd` into a large repo, it can take a 30+ seconds, for the prompt to respond since it needs to review the git repo first.

It is possible to set up my `.bashrc` so that I can either whitelist my small repos for the git prompt to display, or blacklist my large repos so it doesn't load the git prompt?
Alternatively, I'd be happy with a flag/variable that I have to set to enable the git prompt.

The relevant part of my `.bashrc` looks like this:

```
##
# Git prompt options
##
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1 " (\[\033[01;33m\]%s\[\033[00m\])")\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1 " (\[\033[01;33m\]%s\[\033[00m\])")\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the code - the real work is done in a function `__git_ps1`, which is called from inside the prompt.

Replace this function by your own function, e.g.

```
# this is only a outline of possible code 
function myFancyGitPS1() {
   case $(pwd) in
      */someDir/*)
           specialHandling
           ;;
      *)
           __git_ps1 " (\[\033[01;33m\]%s\[\033[00m\])"
          ;;
   esac
}
```

Comment: *groans* It's always the obvious solutions that are so hard to see... Thanks heaps :) It's working perfectly now.